# Update observable on click

Tags: knockout.js

I am facing an issue in knockout js and couldn't find any solution to it, I have a list of objects which I place in an observable array and display them in a table, clicking on a row, populates the object attributes in appropriate fields.

When any field data is updated, it is immediately reflected in table but I want than when I click on Save button than the data must be updated in table so that I can also update that data in database through ajax.
A simple fiddle is created at: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ikbalouch/R5yNM/2/)

Javascript is as:

```
var myData = [{'Id':1,'UserName':'Imran',Active:true},{'Id':2,'UserName':'Khan',Active:false},{'Id':3,'UserName':'Balouch',Active:true}];
function User(id,name,active)
{
   this.Id = ko.observable(id);   
   this.UserName = ko.observable(name);
   this.Active = ko.observable(active);
}
var viewModel = function () {
   var self = this;

   self.AllUsers = ko.observableArray([]);
   self.CurrentUser = ko.observable(new User(-1,'',false));

   var mappedUsers = $.map(myData, function (item) {
       return new User(item.Id, item.UserName, item.Active);
   });

   self.AllUsers(mappedUsers);

   self.GetUser = function(item)
   {
       ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.AllUsers(), function (mainItem) {
           if (item.Id == mainItem.Id)
               self.CurrentUser(mainItem);
       });
   };

   // I want this function to update the table and also send Ajax call.
   self.UpdateRecord = function()
   {
       //ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.AllUsers(), function (mainItem) {
       //    if (self.CurrentUser().Id() == mainItem.Id())
       //        mainItem.UserName = self.CurrentUser().UserName();
       //});
   };
};
$(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
    });
```

and the html is as:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
<tbody data-bind="foreach:AllUsers">
    <tr data-bind="click:$root.GetUser">
        <td data-bind="text:Id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text:UserName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text:Active"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<input type="text" data-bind="value:CurrentUser().UserName"/>
<br/>
<button data-bind="click:UpdateRecord">Save</button>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: You should read these articles: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html and http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html

Comment: @nemesv thanks a lot for the link, I already went through the first link but couldn't find the second one in my searches, I am going through it and I feel that its going to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:
    `mainItem.UserName = 'ABC';`
by:
    `mainItem.UserName('ABC');`

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R5yNM/5/

Comment: Even though I fix the issue by the second link provided by nemesv but still as your answer is fixing my issue so m marking it as answer.